# Why doesn't pip install dependencies specified in setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I built a Python package with a setup.py that looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
     name='my_package',
     version='0.1',
     url='https://github.com/me/my_package',
     download_url='https://github.com/dwnlod.tar.gz',
     author='me',
     author_email='myname@email.com',
     license='MIT',
     packages=['my_package'],
     install_requires=[
         'numpy',
         'other_package'
     ]
)
```

When I install the package locally with

```
pip install .
```

Pip installs all the dependencies in install_requires. However, when I register the package through PyPI, and use

```
pip install my_package
```

Pip does not install the dependencies. (I did this with a fresh environment, so the packages are not installed already; the install fails.) What's going on? Reading through the documentation, it looks like maybe something like

```
     install_requires=[
         'numpy==1.14.1',
         'other_package==ve.rs.ion'
     ]
```

Might work better, because the versions are specified. Could this be the problem?

Here is a link to the repo:

[PyCDA on GitHub](https://github.com/AlliedToasters/PyCDA)
[PyCDA on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pycda/)

Comment: Are you sure the packages aren't already installed?

Comment: Yeah, I created a new environment to test the install process; the install fails due to uninstalled dependencies :(

Comment: Can you link the package or source? it's impossible to know what's wrong given the information provided

Comment: Aye, I can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `setup.py` contains the following line:

```
path = pkg_resources.resource_filename('pycda', 'models/tinynet.h5')
```

Based on the traceback I get when trying to install your package, this call makes `pkg_resources` try to import your package, but your package imports `numpy`.  Because `numpy` can't be installed unless pip knows it's a dependency, and because it can't know it's a dependency without running `setup.py`, and because `setup.py` can't run without first making the above `pkg_resources` call, we end up in the situation that `numpy` is required before we can know it's required; hence, an error.  The solution is to delete the above line, which should be easy, as the `path` variable isn't even used!